# Excel extract issues with running same extract multiple times

Tags: vba, excel, vb6, extract

I'm building an extract and I came across a small issue. If I run the extract once (from VB6 application) - everything works fine. At the end of the Function I do this....

```
xlbook.close
Set xlSheetInfo = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
```

I let the user view the extract, however, once it's closed, EXCEL is still being shown as one of the process in Task Manager. So when I try to run it again, I get an error...

```
91 object variable or with block variable not set
```

and I get an error on this line of code here....

```
With xlSheetSurvey.Range("A5:S5").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter <----- here i get an error
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .Font.Bold = True
end with
end with
```

Why is this happening??? I want it to run multiple times in a row and it's just not letting me do that

Answer (score 0):

So what i was doing is not referencing the range correctly when I was applying my alignment, font and so forth. I changed it to this and it works beautifully...

```
xlsheetsurvey.Range("A5:S5").Horizontalalignment = xlCenter
xlsheetsurvey.range("A5:S5").verticalalignment=xlbottom
```

.... and so forth. I removed the with statement and in every single instance where i reference RANGE, i made sure i reference it excactly to the sheet i was using. Thanks!